# How to calculate distance (similarity) between two continuous random samples with different length using python?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution

I want to calculate similarity or distance between two sample sets. 
Each set indicates game play times of a user. 
For example, suppose there are two users and the first user (X1) play five times, and the other one play four times as four times as follows.

`X1={1,2,3,1,2}` 
`X2={1,2,3,4}`

I want to calculate similarity or distance between `X1` and `X2` using python.
How can I calculate it?

Note 1. the order is not important. 
I mean, {1,2,3,4} and {4,1,2,3} should be considered as the same set.

Note 2. element (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4) is not fixed. I mean, the play time is a continuous variable.

Comment: First, you must define the problem: are these sample *sets* or unordered collections?  A set does not have duplicate values.  Since you cite the length as a problem, I assume that you have a collection.

Comment: Second, you must define what you mean by distance between the two sets.  Since you're not using any standard distance metric, you have to define your own.  We can't do much for you until you supply that metric.

Comment: You will also have to explain what you mean by the collections being "continuous random samples", in terms of that distance metric.  Overall, you seem to be looking for design help (generally not a Stack Overflow issue) for a problem paradigm that you haven't yet specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use Kolmogorov-Smirnov 2 samples test, from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html, described [here](https://www.real-statistics.com/non-parametric-tests/goodness-of-fit-tests/two-sample-kolmogorov-smirnov-test/#:%7E:text=The%20two%2Dsample%20Kolmogorov%2DSmirnov,come%20from%20the%20same%20distribution.&text=As%20for%20the%20Kolmogorov%2DSmirnov,%CE%B1%20is%20the%20critical%20value.)

It should work for samples of different size.

In Python, e.g.

```
import scipy.stats as st    

x = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
y = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
z = np.random.normal(1.1,0.9,1000)

st.ks_2samp(x, y)
st.ks_2samp(x, z)
```

It returns D statistics (as well as p-value), which is the absolute max distance (supremum) between the CDFs of the two samples. This is your distance. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57885/how-to-interpret-p-value-of-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-python) for details

Comment: Your example would be more compelling if you generated different sample sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is the answer I want.